# STM32 Differential ADC

Tags: stm32, adc

Let's assume I use an OPA1632 differential amplifier and I need to connect its output to a microcontroller (in this case: stm32f407 or stm32f429i).
If I'm not mistaken, I would need an ADC with differential input on the microcontroller, right?
In the two microcontroller datasheets (407 and 429) I can't find anywhere a reference to a differential ADC.. so I assume these two boards don't have it?  Right? Or did I misread the datasheet?

Forgive my ignorance, but could I connect the first output terminal of the OP1632 to the ADC1 pin and the second output terminal to another ADC2 pin? Then, via software, I make the difference... right?
I may have said something stupid... but it's the first time I've worked with ADCs.

Comment: Could you link to spec sheets/reference manuals so it is easier to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [STM32F405 RM](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0090-stm32f405415-stm32f407417-stm32f427437-and-stm32f429439-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) it does not look like this device has a differential mode.

When compared to a higher end model [STM32H7](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0399-stm32h745755-and-stm32h747757-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) this clearly mentions a differential mode.
You are correct you could just subtract two ADC channels in software to create a differential mode.

This question is discussed in several places easily found with a search engine of your choice:

[ST Forum](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubemx-mcus/adc-input-voltage-range-in-differential-mode/m-p/287642/highlight/true#M14797)

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/dk5gft/stm32_differential_adc/)

Comment: Thinking about it a little, I don't think the 2 ADC ports work exactly  at the same time! So maybe I could have problems with this "coarse" solution of mine and therefore produce an untrue result from the ADC. Thanks anyway for your reply

Comment: If your device has 2 ADCs they can be triggered at the same time to get a better result, but unless you are interested in really high frequency signals you could just average out a few samples